# Java Project Template

Tags: jakarta-ee

We are starting to build a large middle tier java application (webservices, etc.,).  I want to create a template project, so it can used for any other future projects.

Here is what i am thinking of defining in the template project:

1. Caching mechanism (for look up and other meta information)
2. Exception handling
3. Logging
4. Needed third party frameworks (build, test, spring)
   any thing else that can be included here?

I am looking for expert suggestions on each of these areas:
1)

1. I am thinking ehCache, any comments on this?  positives, negatives or alternatives?
2. I dont want developers just to use blanket try/catch blocks.. some mechanism to automatically catch those and log it and configure in a way we want.  any suggestions?
3. log4j
4. I think i will go with Maven, JUnit and Spring; any other 3rd party frameworks worth considering?  I dont want to discuss maven versus ant, etc.,

Thank you,

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mesir/ povies a template jee project with most of the things u already described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exception Handling**: If you pick spring framework then you would get some help in this regards

- I say spring provides [exception translation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html) for persistence layer so no boiler plate code
- I think if you cannot recover and finish the task on hand why not just make it a RuntimeException
- I am not big fan of expressing a business rule as an exception (ex: PatientNotFoundException just from my personal experience)

**Log4j**: I would just say use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) abstraction

**Maven**: I think Maven is a good build tool as any, I would recommend you to look into [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), Since it is a new project it might be worth while to have a look

I would also add that, It is worth while to invest some time into [**Continuous Integration**](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) and tools like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or Bamboo